# Grails outputs garbage HTML like so: �����

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I've started hitting a problem in Grails 2.0 where my HTML will render fine until I add a CSS `<link>` or `<g:include>` in some way that upsets it and the output becomes like:

��ZaS�8�ίP���8Ii{%�oҖ�2��^

[This](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?98591-GrailsMelody-plugin-shows-garbage-screen) is the only thing I can find describing a similar problem. I'm not using the UI Performance plugin but I suspect it has something to do with the resource plugin. I don't see any errors in the resource debug spew. I use other optimization plugins, but they're disabled in development where I am experiencing this.

Any ideas on how to figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: can you give a specific example? How does the css that break your page look like?

Answer (score 0):

What this came down to was a bad g:include in a layout file. No exception was exposed to me so perhaps Sitemesh tries to deal with it and the result is often ugly.